# How to automatically sum in excel for filtered data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am going to build a TIME SHEET. I want to sum the total amount of hours worked for a project chosen from drop-down menu.

[image]

**Total Worked Hours for Project No 4** will be the total hours worked for project no 4 e.g. 50 Hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a combination of VLOOKUP() and SUMIF().

SUMIF() allows you to check the value of the cell before summing, or check the value of a cell in one range before summing a cell in another range.

For example,

[image: Examples of two forms of SUMIF()]

Comment: Thanks Boss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, sorry for belated response,That saved my time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reference the value of the cell directly!

So, if the drop down list is in cell A1, then this is your value (the value of A1)! In your case, just reference $B$8

This means you don't need to stick it else where, but instead just use a [VLookUp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb224766%28v=office.12%29.aspx) function.

---

Original Answer (partly incorrect as I hadn't realised how the OP had implemented the drop down list)

I offer this as an option where you don't need to use Macros. I'm sure there will be a more elegant way, but this will suffice.

Create a new worksheet in your Excel file, call it Result. Right click on the drop down list, format control and select the cell link - choose A1 in your new worksheet.

Now, you can reference this cell so you can perform a look up and concatenate this new value.

In my example below, I have 1 combo box, and the selected value is G4

[image]

As you can, see, it displays the value 15 as it should be

The code in cell F11 is

```
=VLOOKUP(G4,I2:J8,2)
```

When I select change the value in the drop down list, to a 9, for example, it displays 50 in my value cell.

At this stage, you should be able to update your code so it can perform the maths for you as well.

Comment: Dave Rook,Thanks ,but i need all to be done in a single sheet since it to be TIME SHEET.

Comment: @SheriffAzleum You *can* still do this. My example was showing you how to do it, the details will be up to you!